# Determining maximum usable memory android app

Tags: android, performance, jvm, heap-memory

I have an arraylist of byte array ( `Arraylist<byte[]>`). I am trying to read maximum amount of bytes from a file into memory.What's the best way to do it. How can i know the maximum available memory to be used.
I intend to avoid any outofmemory exceptions and lags

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I am not aware of any method of determining what the largest free memory block is. Even if there *were* such a method, by the time you go around to use that information, the answer may be different (e.g., some memory was allocated, carved out of that block). You can use `ActivityManager` to find out your maximum heap size (e.g., `getMemoryClass()`), but that will be far larger than the largest block that you can allocate.

Comment: Can i take a fixed size(Say like 15). There must be some way to ensure that this will work for every device. I have taken buffer size 1024 * 60 so i am not really confident about this.